# Having issues with significant frame drops on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, asyncdisplaykit

I am currently struggling to achieve building a GUI that is somewhat similar to the Netflix app for iOS (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68sVK.jpg). As you can see, it has several horizontal scrollviews with multiple elements in them, all located in another vertical scrollview.

I achieved to have a similar GUI but now I'm struggling with improving performance. Scrolling through the vertical scrollview looks choppy. I have researched into ways of how making performance better and I found a library that apparently solves this issue: the Async Display Kit from FB (http://asyncdisplaykit.org/). Sadly there's no currently binding available.

So, given that I cannot use that library, my question is... what would be a good method for maintaining performance and fps?. Of course, I already remove from the superview all views that are not in bounds for the screen.

Thank you.-